# File Upload With Progress Bar displayed like a table

Tags: php, mysql, file, file-upload

im looking to implement a file upload to my site

i have researched so many file upload scripts and cant seem to find one thats easy to use and modify at the same time

i dont mind the look and functions of this one but cant seem to implement it properly as a demo on my own server and being able to store the url in a database

http://www.plupload.com/examples/queue

any help is very much apreciated

Comment: Then what is the issue ?

Comment: i cant seem to work out how to store the information in the database

Comment: Which URL you want to store in Database ? What code you used ? Give me link to your server .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jxe7pey8/

Comment: Which URL you want to store in Database ? What code you used ?